# Run an already compiled unit test with Maven

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I would like to know if it is possible to run a previously compiled test (using `mvn test-compile`) without having to recompile a project and its tests. I'm aware of the `mvn -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod test` command, but it does not fit my need.

More generally I'm trying to find a way to run unit tests is a specific order using a list of test names. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to run the tests in a specific order ? This is generally considered a bad practice. Tests should be independent of each other and thus independent of order ...

Comment: If the tests cannot be run in arbitrary order, it would be better to fix that instead of trying to go around it with Maven tricks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start maven by calling a phase it will execute all lifecycle phases up to the one you are calling. For example, when calling

```
mvn test
```

all the phases before the test lifecycle phase will be execute too: the project will be validated, sources and resources will be generated and processed, sources will be compiled, the same will happen to test sources and resources and finally unit tests will be run.

But you can also call the plugin goal that is bound to a lifecycle phase. In the case of the test phase the bound goal is surefire's test mojo. So you could call

```
mvn surefire:test
```

and no other lifecycle phase will be executed.

Comment: Definitely what I needed, thank you very much.

Comment: If it helped, please mark the answer as accepted with a green check mark :)

Comment: Had to wait 10min to do it. Done !