# workspace sharing between master/slave in jenkins when using external workspace manager plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using External Workspace Manager plugin in Jenkins. And I am facing problem which workspace is not shared between nodes(master and slave).

What I am trying to do is.

1. Build is done in master node.
2. Deployment(or test) is done in slave node).

Everytime I run the pipeline, I can see that new directories are made in slave node, but it's always empty.

This is my pipeline script:

```
stage ('Stage 1. Allocate workspace')
def extWorkspace = exwsAllocate diskPoolId: 'diskpool1'

node('master'){
    exws (extWorkspace) {
        stage('Stage 2. Build on the build server')

        git url: 'https://github.com/alexsomai/dummy-hello-world.git'
        def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean install -DskipTests"
        
    }
}

node ('agent-one') {
    exws (extWorkspace) {
        stage('Stage 3. Run tests on a test machine')

        def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn test"
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with `Pipeline` script?

**below is the error message**

```
Started by user admin
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] stage
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated

[Pipeline] exwsAllocate
Disk allocation strategy was not provided as step parameter. Fallback to the strategy defined in the Jenkins global config
Using Disk allocation strategy: 'Select the Disk with the most usable space'
Selected Disk ID 'disk1' from the Disk Pool ID 'diskpool1'
The path on Disk is: jenkins-project/disk1/external-workspace/Workspace reuse in same job/88


[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/external-workspace/Workspace reuse in same job


[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] exws
Searching for disk definitions in the External Workspace Templates from Jenkins global config
Running in /var/jenkins_home/jenkins-project/disk1/external-workspace/Workspace reuse in same job/88


[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated

[Pipeline] git
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/alexsomai/dummy-hello-world.git
git init /var/jenkins_home/jenkins-project/disk1/external-workspace/Workspace reuse in same job/88 # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/alexsomai/dummy-hello-world.git
git --version # timeout=10
git --version # 'git version 2.39.2'
git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/alexsomai/dummy-hello-world.git refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/alexsomai/dummy-hello-world.git # timeout=10
git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 5b64cdb7d2088534abc9911c1782c452842e77a4 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
git checkout -f 5b64cdb7d2088534abc9911c1782c452842e77a4 # timeout=10
git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
git checkout -b master 5b64cdb7d2088534abc9911c1782c452842e77a4 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Write dummy operation class to have multiple tests"
git rev-list --no-walk 5b64cdb7d2088534abc9911c1782c452842e77a4 # timeout=10

[Pipeline] sh
chmod 777 ./pom.xml
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] sh
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/M3/bin/mvn clean install -DskipTests


[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< com.example:dummy-hello-world >--------------------
[INFO] Building dummy-hello-world 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ dummy-hello-world ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ dummy-hello-world ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/jenkins_home/jenkins-project/disk1/external-workspace/Workspace reuse in same job/88/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ dummy-hello-world ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files with javac [debug target 1.8] to target/classes
[WARNING] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ dummy-hello-world ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/jenkins_home/jenkins-project/disk1/external-workspace/Workspace reuse in same job/88/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ dummy-hello-world ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :dependency
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files with javac [debug target 1.8] to target/test-classes
[WARNING] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- surefire:3.2.2:test (default-test) @ dummy-hello-world ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ dummy-hello-world ---
[INFO] Building jar: /var/jenkins_home/jenkins-project/disk1/external-workspace/Workspace reuse in same job/88/target/dummy-hello-world-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ dummy-hello-world ---
[INFO] Installing /var/jenkins_home/jenkins-project/disk1/external-workspace/Workspace reuse in same job/88/pom.xml to /root/.m2/repository/com/example/dummy-hello-world/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dummy-hello-world-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /var/jenkins_home/jenkins-project/disk1/external-workspace/Workspace reuse in same job/88/target/dummy-hello-world-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /root/.m2/repository/com/example/dummy-hello-world/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dummy-hello-world-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.604 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-20T10:26:58+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // exws
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] node
Running on agent-one in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/external-workspace/Workspace reuse in same job
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] exws
Searching for disk definitions in the External Workspace Templates from Jenkins global config
Searching for disk definitions in the Node config
Running in /var/jenkins_home/jenkins-project/disk1/external-workspace/Workspace reuse in same job/88
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] sh

/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/M3/bin/mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.172 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-20T10:27:01+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/var/jenkins_home/jenkins-project/disk1/external-workspace/Workspace reuse in same job/88). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // exws
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

How to run successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of notes from someone who runs a Jenkins instance as a service for 90+ teams:

1. Building on the master node isn't generally considered a good practice. It leads to overloading the master node.
2. When you run `mvn install`, the artifacts are installed to the local Maven .m2 repository, not to a workspace. Since the .m2 repository is usually shared between all the builds on a node to save time on downloading the dependencies and Maven places both dependencies and artifacts into the same repo, `mvn install` itself might not be a good idea in a CI/CD environment - at least without a subsequent cleanup in the end of the build.
3. `mvn test` will still run all the previous lifecycle phases, plus, "sharing" a workspace between different machines, even if possible, would mean sending a potentially large amount of artifacts between over the network. Which, in combination with p.2, makes little to no sense in real life.

To sum up, I wouldn't recommend the approach you're trying to use - just run everything on a build agent. Then, if you want to split the building, testing, and deployment activities between the stages, run the plugin goals instead of lifecycle phases in the subsequent stages, like shown in [Run an already compiled unit test with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840208/run-an-already-compiled-unit-test-with-maven/69840272#69840272).